# Apache Spark: spark-submit using java springboot app showing Error: Failed to load class com.group.dr.myApp

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark, spring-boot-maven-plugin

i am new to Apache Spark, Springboot: i am trying to spark-submit the java springboot app, but i am getting

```
 
Error: Failed to load class Error: Failed to load class com.group.dr.myApp.
24/02/27 16:01:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
24/02/27 16:01:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C://..
```

while i suspect its the problem with packaging, i am using

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId
```

i tried multiple options like instead using

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
```

but couldnt resolve this.

This is the submit-spark cammand i am using.
`spark-submit --class com.group.dr.myApp --master local[*]  dr-0.0.1.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED`

i tried answers on similar qsts but none worked for me.

versions:
Java 17,
Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.13